# Neo4j get all nodes and relationships that are below selected node

Tags: neo4j

I need to do query through Rest Api to get all highlighted nodes as shown at this picture. I need to get all nodes that connected with selected node and all nodes that are connected with prev nodes and etc. Like shown at this picture.

**Question: Can I do this by one query?**

[image: Database structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not 100% clear, but if you want to get all nodes be following outgoing relationships, you could do:

```
MATCH (g:Group {id: 'whatever'})-[*1..10]->(other_node)
RETURN other_node
```

That will give you all nodes within a distance of 10